# Batch file to resort to Windows Photo Viewer

Tags: windows

Windows 10.
Microsoft continuously keep removing the default photo viewer which I have set to Windows Photo Viewer.
Is there a batch file that will restore this setting?

Answer (score 1):

The batch file modifies the necessary registry values to set Windows Photo Viewer as the default photo viewer for various image file extensions (e.g., `.bmp`, `.jpg`, `.png`). After running the batch file, Windows Photo Viewer should be restored as the default photo viewer for those file types.

```
@echo off

REM Restoring Windows Photo Viewer as the default photo viewer

REM Set the necessary registry values for Windows Photo Viewer
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bmp\UserChoice" /v Progid /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Bitmap" /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.dib\UserChoice" /v Progid /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Bitmap" /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.gif\UserChoice" /v Progid /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.GIF" /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jpeg\UserChoice" /v Progid /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.JFIF" /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jpg\UserChoice" /v Progid /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.JFIF" /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jpe\UserChoice" /v Progid /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.JFIF" /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jfif\UserChoice" /v Progid /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.JFIF" /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice" /v Progid /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Png" /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.tif\UserChoice" /v Progid /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff" /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.tiff\UserChoice" /v Progid /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff" /f

echo Windows Photo Viewer has been restored as the default photo viewer.

pause
```

Comment: Just removed the file associations ...